# How to automating title and filename synchronization in Quarto Markdown with Lua filters?

Tags: lua, yaml, pandoc, quarto

I am authoring a Quarto markdown document, an extension of the Pandoc markdown system, and am crafting a YAML section to generate a PDF. My objective is to assign identical text to both the title and the filename. However, the current requirement to duplicate the text for the `title` and `output-file` fields is excessively verbose and cumbersome. Is there a method, perhaps through a Lua filter, to reference the value of `title` and apply it to `output-file`?

```
---
title: "\\Large \\textbf{Awesome title but Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet}"
format:
  pdf:
    output-ext: "pdf"
    output-file: "Awesome title but Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet"
---

foo bar
```

## MWE

I have attempted to create a Lua filter named `set-output-file.lua`, but I am concerned that it may not successfully access the value of `meta.format.pdf['output-file']`.

```lua
-- file: set-output-file.lua
function Meta(meta)
  if meta.title then
    -- Remove LaTeX commands and special characters to create a valid filename
    local filename = pandoc.utils.stringify(meta.title)
    filename = filename:gsub("\\%a+", ""):gsub("[^%w%s]", ""):gsub("%s+", "_")
    -- Check if format.pdf exists, if not create it
    if not meta.format then meta.format = pandoc.MetaMap({}) end
    if not meta.format.pdf then meta.format.pdf = pandoc.MetaMap({}) end
    -- Set the output-file within the pdf sub-table
    meta.format.pdf['output-file'] = filename
  end
  return meta
end
```

```
---
title: "\\Large \\textbf{Awesome title but Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet}"
format:
  pdf:
    output-ext: "pdf"
filters:
  - set-output-file.lua
---

foo bar
```

Comment: I didn't test your code. But if you want bold and large test as a title, I guess it might be much better to edit the Latex macro used for setting the title than hard coding it in your YAML file. This might also influence any Lua filter because you wouldn't have to remove those Latex commands.

Comment: @lukeflo You might be right, and I should have to stick to LaTeX by chainging a LaTeX template to achieve what I want to get.